# What is the best approaches for comments?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, comments

I have a Detail page and every user can add a comment to this page. I simply want to separate the comments by simply giving a css property i.e. border bottom and want to display different color when mouse over this comment as whole div or box.  On the other hand, I have look at many web samples, but I have not found an approach performing these features. There is a similar comment box on [this](https://en.forums.wordpress.com/topic/removing-comment-box-for-twenty-eleven-with-css-custom-design) page, but I want to change the box color on hover. Any sample pls?

Comment: @Downwoters: Do not you have any idea regarding to solution? It is better to post the answers instead of downvote and if you do not know anything regarding to the solution it is better to be keep out!..

Comment: Using Google is too hard?

Comment: @MikeSW I think you do not read the questions fully. Please re-read my question again and inform me if you still not understand **.. I have look at many web samples, but I have not found an approach performing these features...**.

Comment: I understood very well your question. But waiting for answers on a silver platter seems to be  the norm these days

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
.comment-container {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}
.comment-container:hover {
    background: #ccc;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. Unfortunately someone has not understand the issue and vote downed the question. I hope you do not?

Comment: It wasn't me downvoting.